# Python datetime library that is daylight savings aware when adding days to datetime

Tags: python, datetime

Is there a python datetime library that does this?

```
dt = iso8601.parse_date("2016-03-13 00:00:00-08")
dt = dt.astimezone(us_pacific)
dt += timedelta(days=1)
self.assertEqual(dt, iso8601.parse_date("2016-03-14 00:00:00-07"))
```

In other words, I'm looking for a library where the datetime object is smart enough to know that timedelta(days=1) is NOT the same as timedelta(hours=24) (bonus points for supporting months).

Currently, I'm finding the least bug-hazard workaround is to use dates and then convert that to a datetime with the time set to 0 in the given timezone. The issue though is that its easy to assume the code above will work as given, so I would like to work with a library where that is not a risk. Likewise, if you're given a datetime object, its a nuisance to convert back into dates.

**Edit:**

This was put on hold since asking if there is a software library that accomplishes a task vs. having to code it out by scratch is offtopic. I'm not sure how to better phrase, since I've already explained the workaround is to work with dates and then add the time later, which can be done in various ways. I'm looking for a BETTER way, which I already know isn't part of the python standard library. I'm pretty sure asking "is there a better way to do this?", or "how can I get accomplish this in about the same number of lines of code?" are perfectly valid questions as well.

If there's no library that does such a thing, I could certainly make it. I'd call it YADateTime because it would be yet another python date time library. That said, if there's already a library there's no point in me making one.

Comment: I guess that when doing date calculations you could convert all date/times to GMT/UTC, do the arithmetic, then convert to local time. Have you tried this?

Comment: @barny that does the opposite of what the question asks.

Comment: Months are harder, because there's some ambiguity in what Jan 31 + one month should return.

Comment: @MarkRansom I prefer to think of my suggestion as a way of achieving the objective of the question, actually. I haven't noticed a "better" suggestion from you - got one?

Comment: @barny but that doesn't work because there are days in the year that are 23 or 25 hours long. To get the *same time* in local time you must get *different* times in UTC.

Comment: So you are saying that there is no algorithmic conversion possible between local time and GMT/UTC? That doesn't seem likely. Chaos would reign. Yes, I know "time" is an intangible beast but I don't believe that conversion between local and GMT/UTC is not possible.

Comment: I'd very much argue that `timedelta(days=1)` should always equal `timedelta(hours=24)`, just that dates within daylight savings period know to offset themselves by 1-3 hours I wonder if you could just put a `property` wrapper around `hour` attribute of the datetime object...

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen no, a day is a day, not 24 hours. Similarly a month is a month, not x number of days.

Comment: To the OP, you're mixing types here, ie.  `point_in_time_with_second_resolution + duration_with_day_resolution`. You're unlikely to find a satisfactory solution.

Comment: I looked at maya's source code, it didn't appear to deal with this case. I looked at pendulum which was well tested and it likewise didn't have any tests that indicated it handled this. The existing datetime libraries seem to be, for the most part, convenience wrappers over other datetime libraries.

Comment: If Maya doesn't cover this case I recommend creating an issue for it ;)

Comment: I did not test it, but [pytz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz/) comes to mind.

Comment: Have you looked at parsedatetime? It seems pretty intelligent and may meet your needs. https://github.com/bear/parsedatetime. I've heard good things about Arrow (http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/) as well but I've personally used neither.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on Python 3.6.4. The day was added correctly according to the timezone-aware datetime objects (i.e. the date incremented and the hour stayed at 0). The problem I had was that the timezone offset was not correct.

Not pretty, but it seems to work.

```
EST = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
DAY = dt.timedelta(days = 1)

date = date + DAY
date_with_correct_timezone = EST.localize(dt.datetime(date.year,date.month,date.day,hour,minute,0))
if date != date_with_correct_timezone:
    print(f'     corrected {date} to {date_with_correct_timezone}')
    date = date_with_correct_timezone
```

Example Output:

```
corrected 2017-03-13 00:00:00-05:00 to 2017-03-13 00:00:00-04:00
corrected 2017-11-06 00:00:00-04:00 to 2017-11-06 00:00:00-05:00
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but it's a *useful* question, and I didn't find any newer version of it on SO, so I'm adding an answer here.

At minimum, one should be able to take a datetime of `2022-03-13 01:30:00` in the `America/Chicago` timezone, which is just before the DST "spring forward" from 2am to 3am, add an hour to it, and get `2022-03-13 03:30:00` in the same `America/Chicago` time zone.

This isn't even adding an interval of varying length, it's just crossing a DST boundary, so it should be "easy".

The following things fail that all *look* like they should work:

```py
# 0a. pytz timezone, datetime.timedelta math
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
tz = pytz.timezone('America/Chicago')
d = datetime(2022, 3, 13, 1, 30, tzinfo=tz)  # already well-known to be wrong
result = d + timedelta(hours=1)
str(result)
# '2022-03-13 02:30:00-05:51'
# Wrong ↑
```

```py
# 1a. pytz timezone, datetime.timedelta math
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
tz = pytz.timezone('America/Chicago')
d = tz.localize(datetime(2022, 3, 13, 1, 30))
result = d + timedelta(hours=1)
str(result)
# '2022-03-13 02:30:00-06:00'
# Wrong ↑
```

```py
# 2a. dateutil timezone, datetime.timedelta math, method 1
import dateutil.tz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
tz = dateutil.tz.gettz('America/Chicago')
d = datetime(2022, 3, 13, 1, 30, tzinfo=tz)
result = d + timedelta(hours=1)
str(result)
# '2022-03-13 02:30:00-05:00'
# Wrong ↑
```

```py
# 3a. dateutil timezone, datetime.timedelta math, method 2
import dateutil.tz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
tz = dateutil.tz.gettz('America/Chicago')
d = datetime(2022, 3, 13, 1, 30).astimezone(tz)
result = d + timedelta(hours=1)
str(result)
# '2022-03-13 02:30:00-05:00'
# Wrong ↑
```

```py
# 4a. dateutil timezone, pendulum math
import dateutil.tz
from datetime import datetime
import pendulum
tz = dateutil.tz.gettz('America/Chicago')
d = datetime(2022, 3, 13, 1, 30).astimezone(tz)
result = pendulum.instance(d).add(hours=1)
str(result)
# '2022-03-13T02:30:00-06:00'
# Wrong ↑
```

Some of those can be rescued by converting the result to a `timestamp` (seconds since epoch GMT) and back again, and reapplying the timezone - obviously something that really should not have to be done:

```py
# 1b. pytz timezone, datetime.timedelta math
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
tz = pytz.timezone('America/Chicago')
d = tz.localize(datetime(2022, 3, 13, 1, 30))
result = d + timedelta(hours=1)
result = datetime.fromtimestamp(result.timestamp()).astimezone(tz)
str(result)
# '2022-03-13 03:30:00-05:00'
# Correct ↑
```

```py
# 2b. dateutil timezone, datetime.timedelta math, method 1
import dateutil.tz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
tz = dateutil.tz.gettz('America/Chicago')
d = datetime(2022, 3, 13, 1, 30, tzinfo=tz)
result = d + timedelta(hours=1)
result = datetime.fromtimestamp(result.timestamp()).astimezone(tz)
str(result)
# '2022-03-13 01:30:00-06:00'
# Wrong ↑ (worse!)
```

```py
# 3b. dateutil timezone, datetime.timedelta math, method 2
import dateutil.tz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
tz = dateutil.tz.gettz('America/Chicago')
d = datetime(2022, 3, 13, 1, 30).astimezone(tz)
result = d + timedelta(hours=1)
result = datetime.fromtimestamp(result.timestamp()).astimezone(tz)
str(result)
# '2022-03-13 01:30:00-06:00'
# Wrong ↑ (worse!)
```

```py
# 4b. dateutil timezone, pendulum math
import dateutil.tz
from datetime import datetime
import pendulum
tz = dateutil.tz.gettz('America/Chicago')
d = datetime(2022, 3, 13, 1, 30).astimezone(tz)
result = pendulum.instance(d).add(hours=1)
result = datetime.fromtimestamp(result.timestamp()).astimezone(tz)
str(result)
# '2022-03-13 03:30:00-05:00'
# Correct ↑
```